# following NoSuchMethodError thrown building FutureBuilder<DocumtSnapshot<Object?>>(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState<DocumentSnapshot<Object?>

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../../Authentication/FirebaseServices.dart';

class SellersubCatList extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String id = 'SellersubCatList-screen';

  FirebaseServices _service = FirebaseServices();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    DocumentSnapshot? args =
        ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as DocumentSnapshot<Object>;
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          elevation: 0,
          shape: Border(
            bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
          title: Text(
            args['catName'],
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18),
          ),
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
            future: _service.categories.doc(args.id).get(),
            builder: (BuildContext context,
                AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text("Something went wrong");

              }
              if (snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.data!.exists) {
                return Text("Document does not exist");
              }

              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              }
              var data = snapshot.data!['subCat'];

              return Container(
                child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: data.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 8),
                        child: ListTile(
                          onTap: () {
                            // subCat
                          },
                          title: Text(
                            data[index],
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }),
              );
            },
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

When I tap on a button its open but its seems like tis

Comment: Can you writeup what you are expecting?

Comment: please put all the code in code style.